# Помогите найти ошибку в коде ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side в js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вот код:

```
var fogot = true,counter = 0;
for (var j = 0; j <= $('.flex-dir-row .one-good').length; j++) {
    alert(0);
    if((j % (2*6)) == 0){
        $(".goods-container").css("height") = (parseInt($(".goods-container").css("height")) + 100) + "%";
    }
}
$(".slide-button").click(function(){
    if(counter <= Math.floor(j/12)){
        $(".goods-container").css({"animation":"moveToTop 1s linear forwards"});
        counter++;
        alert(1);
    } else {
        $(".goods-container").css({"animation":"moveToBottom 1s linear forwards"});
        counter--;
        alert(0);
    }
});
```

Comment: Уточнение:пишет что ощибка на строке 5.

Comment: в сообщения есть кнопка `править`(под сообщением маленькая такая текстовая кнопка), и уточнения к вопросу лучше с помощью правки вставлять в само сообщение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в использовании метода `css`

Было :

```
$(".goods-container").css("height") = (parseInt($(".goods-container").css("height")) + 100) + "%";
```

Надо :

```
var h = (parseInt($(".goods-container").css("height")) + 100) + "%";
$(".goods-container").css("height", h);
```

Подробней можно почитать например тут [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp) или тут 
[api.jquery](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: обрати внимание на [.css( propertyName, function )](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function) код станет намного проще: `$(".goods-container").css("height", (index, currentValue)=>\`${parseInt(currentValue)+100}%\`);`

Comment: @Grundy прикольно, я и не знал, спс !

Comment: у большинства функций есть перегрузка принимающая функцию